# MOSFET Bootstrap circuit simulation with NGSPICE

Tags: mosfet-driver, spice, powermosfet, ngspice, bootstrap

**Preface**

I am designing a Solid State Relay as an educational exercise, to catch up on what my university did not teach me. I am a long time Linux user and open-source software lover, which brought me to `ngspice` for simulation. I don't have access to professional design software or simulators.

**Context**

I designed a Solid State Relay, had a PCB manufactured, and burned out the gate driver upon testing with a 24VDC supply. I was able to verify that the PCB matches my schematic. I took some measurements and found out that my bootstrap circuit (this is a high-side NMOS switch) doesn't appear to be working correctly. I failed to simulate it before having the PCB manufactured, but my back-of-napkin calculations seemed to say everything was in spec. Now, I am setting out to simulate an updated version of my schematic, which is where I am seeking advice.

**The problem**
[image: Bootstrap Capacitor Schematic]
Please pardon my amateur schematic. As I understand it, `CBOOT1` charges through `D1` from the supply, and when the voltage from `VBOOT` to the source node (in the middle of the two transistors here) rises high enough, Q1 will turn on, discharging the capacitor slowly through any current leaking through the gate. I have elided the gate driver, since I'm trying to just simulate this bootstrapping behavior in AC and DC, for now.

The issue is, `ngspice` cannot simulate this circuit. I have a level 0 model for the BSC220N from Infineon, and everything else is standard simulation-only components. `ngspice` seems to be having trouble inside the transistor model because of the source node between Q1 and Q2.
Interestingly enough, I can simulate the model if I only use one transistor (which would work for DC-only applications), but the results are usually very noisy.

Does anyone have advice on how to get `ngspice` to converge? My SPICE code is below.

Circuit:

```
.title KiCad schematic
.include "/home/andy/workspace/coffee_items/bean_machine_controller/spice/libs/OptiMOS3_200V.lib"
VAC1 Net-_D1-Pad2_ GND dc 0 ac 120 sin(0 120 60)
RG1 Net-_Q1-Pad4_ /VBOOT 3
* CBOOT1 /VBOOT Net-_CBOOT1-Pad2_ 1u
CBOOT1 /VBOOT Net-_Q2-Pad8_ 1u
D1 /VBOOT Net-_D1-Pad2_ BASIC_DIODE
* RLOAD1 Net-_Q2-Pad8_ GND 8
RLOAD1 Net-_Q2-Pad8_ GND 8
XQ1 Net-_D1-Pad2_ Net-_Q1-Pad4_ Net-_Q2-Pad8_ BSC220N20NSFD_L0
* XQ2 Net-_Q2-Pad8_ Net-_Q1-Pad4_ Net-_CBOOT1-Pad2_ BSC220N20NSFD_L0
.end
```

Simulation script:

```
.title "boost circuit simulation"
.control
set ngbehavior=ps
dc vac1 0 120 1
tran 0.1s 10s 0s
option TEMP=27
.endc
.MODEL BASIC_DIODE D()
* .include "/home/andy/workspace/coffee_items/bean_machine_controller/spice/libs/OptiMOS3_200V.lib"
.include "boost_circuit.cir"
```

Invocation:
`ngspice boost_sim.cir`

Output:
`doAnalyses: TRAN:  Timestep too small; time = 0.0193025, timestep = 1.25e-13: trouble with node "e.xq1.eaux#branch"`

Comment: Try this model: `.model BSC320N20NS3 VDMOS(Rg=2.4 Vto=3.7 Rd=23.61m Rs=404u Rb=3.79m Kp=48.7 Lambda=0.015 Cgdmin=6p Cgdmax=0.27n A=0.5 Cgs=1.77n Cjo=2.66n M=0.45 Is=16.8p VJ=0.9 N=1.12 TT=120n ksubthres=.1)`. You may need to enable LTspice compatibility (this is from LTspice). BTW, if you meant to model your source as a 120 V *RMS*, then you should know that the value for the `SIN()` source is the peak value. As it is, your source has ~86 V RMS. This also means you may need to rethink the choice for your switches.

Comment: Interesting, that worked! That model seems close enough to the one I'm using for this to be valid.  I'm getting pretty much the behavior I expected, although after the transistors turn on, they stay on indefinitely. I was expecting the capacitor to discharge pretty quickly. Thanks for the tip on the `SIN()` source as well, I did not even think about that.

Comment: A couple other things to watch out for in KiCad/ngspice is to make sure you have the "Alternate Node Sequence" set properly for those MOSFET symbols you are using.  A VDMOS `.model` statement assumes D-G-S (in that order).  The same applies to the diode too.  KiCad diode symbols have cathode first and anode second, and in SPICE it's opposite of that.  I would also recommend using an actual diode model like a 1N4148 instead of using the default one.  You can post here for more detailed help with KiCad/ngspice interface: https://forum.kicad.info/c/schematic/simulation-ngspice/20